# How to mock Tinkerpop blueprint Vertex and Edge objects?

Tags: java, mocking, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

Is there a way to create a fake Tinkerpop Bluerint Vertex and Edge in Java without being part of a database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an [in-memory TinkerGraph](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerGraph.html). It offers a graph implementation (including vertexes and edges), but it lacks transactions and persistence.

Comment: Thanks..This is what I am currently doing through OrientDB.. But I wouldn't want to involve any database at all since I am trying to test code that gets a vertex and its connected neighbors through edges and converts them to a hierarchy of java class objects.. I need to write unit tests and not integration tests that I already have..

Comment: I saw from the tests of Blueprint Frames that they do
```Graph wrapper = Mockito.mock(Graph.class);``` ```Vertex vertex = Mockito.mock(Vertex.class);``` ```Mockito.when(wrapper.getVertex(1)).thenReturn(vertex);```
I wonder how flexible this is..
https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/blob/master/src/test/java/com/tinkerpop/frames/FramedGraphFactoryTest.java